# please write query as per my needs in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have one table with thousands of records.
Structure of the table is

```
object_id   |   term_taxonomy_id
```

my query is I want all object_ids which have term_taxonomy_id = 280 and term_taxonomy_id = 306

so my output should be like this

```
object_id   |   term_taxonomy_id  |  term_taxonomy_id
1           |   280               |  306
10          |   280               |  306
```

Please write query for this purpose.

EDIT:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `wp_term_relationships` r
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rr ON rr.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships rrr ON rr.term_taxonomy_id = r.term_taxonomy_id
WHERE rrr.term_taxonomy_id =280
AND rr.term_taxonomy_id =306
GROUP BY r.object_id
```

I have written above query.

Comment: please provide proper table structure and also show what efforts you made.

Comment: Its not what you order us to do we cant do your works but we can assist your effort only.. 1st  try to put ur effort on it try many times if not then post here with ur code

Comment: I tried many times and couldn't did it that's why I posted here. Please assist me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a self join is a good idea, but you should join on object_id, not on term_taxonomy_id, and use inner join instead of left:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.object_id, r.term_taxonomy_id, rr.term_taxonomy_id
FROM  `wp_term_relationships` r
INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships rr ON rr.object_id = r.object_id
WHERE r.term_taxonomy_id =280
AND rr.term_taxonomy_id =306
```

Comment: great! it worked like a charm!
Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE term_taxonomy_id = 280 AND term_taxonomy_id = 306
```

AS you told you have one table

Comment: thanks for your answer but it gives me empty result. I have only two fields there.
1. object_id 
2. term_taxonomy_id

Comment: Then you dont have any records of that matches both condition

Comment: Surely you cannot expect a single field to satisfy 2 criteria at the same time connected by an `and`. This query is bound to return an empty resultset.

Comment: As u told you need both condition so i used and

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
object_id
)
FROM wp_term_relationships
WHERE term_taxonomy_id =280
OR term_taxonomy_id =306
```

I found the way to do this.

Comment: This does not comply with your own requirements in the question, since it would list even those object_ids which have only one of the two term_taxonomy_ids. You clearly wrote `and` in the OP.

Comment: yes you are right. that's why I marked your answer as perfect!